# Interpretation of code

Tags: sql, sql-server, events

Reviewing some codes and I stumbling to this SQL code that I don't understand what its doing.

```
INNER JOIN PPORDFIL_SQL 
    on dbo.att_Synergy_Absences.ItemCode = PPORDFIL_SQL.item_no   
    and PPORDFIL_SQL.id in 
        (Select top 1 p2.ID
         from  PPORDFIL_SQL as p2
         where p2.item_no  = PPORDFIL_SQL.item_no 
           and p2.ord_status = PPORDFIL_SQL.ord_status 
           and dbo.att_Synergy_Absences.syscreated <= ppordfil_sql.entered_dt 
         order by p2.id )
```

To my understanding it is suppose to show 1 entry regardless of the earliest regardless of the amount of entry.

For example, there is multiple item of the same item_no but the order number is different so it will only show one entry even if there is multiple of the order number of the same item_no.

I tried to run the code but it didn't work.

Any comment on what it does or did I actually get it right? lol

Comment: This is a great place to start getting an answer. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Your subquery is ordering by ID - maybe is should be ordering by a date field instead?

Answer (score 0):

Your two join conditions are interfering with each other.

Try it like this:

```
INNER JOIN PPORDFIL_SQL on  PPORDFIL_SQL.id = (
  Select top 1 p2.ID 
  from  PPORDFIL_SQL  as p2
  where p2.item_no  = dbo.att_Synergy_Absences.ItemCode 
  and p2.ord_status = PPORDFIL_SQL.ord_status 
  and dbo.att_Synergy_Absences.syscreated <= ppordfil_sql.entered_dt 
  order by p2.id 
)
```